# Why does a queryset applied in a ModelForm not inherit a queryset from a ModelManager?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a custom queryset on a model manager:

```
class TenantManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
       return super().get_queryset().filter(myfield=myvalue)

class TenantModel(TenantModelMixin, models.Model):
    objects = TenantManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I use the abstract `TenantModel` as a mixin with another model to apply the `TenantManager`. E.g.

```
class MyModel(TenantModel):
```

This works as expected, applying the `TenantManager` filter every time `MyModel.objects.all()` is called when inside a view.

However, when I create a `ModelForm` with the model, the filter is not applied and all results (without the filter are returned. For example:

```
class AddPersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('person', )
```

Why is this and how to I ensure the `ModelManager` is applied to the queryset in `ModelForm`?

***Edit***

@Willem suggests the reason is forms use `._base_manager` and not `.objects` (although I can not find this in the Django source code), however the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#don-t-filter-away-any-results-in-this-type-of-manager-subclass) say not to filter this kind of manager, so how does one filter form queries?

> Don’t filter away any results in this type of manager subclass
>
> This
> manager is used to access objects that are related to from some other
> model. In those situations, Django has to be able to see all the
> objects for the model it is fetching, so that anything which is
> referred to can be retrieved.
>
> If you override the get_queryset() method and filter out any rows,
> Django will return incorrect results. Don’t do that. A manager that
> filters results in get_queryset() is not appropriate for use as a base
> manager.

Comment: It uses `._base_manager` iirc, not `.objects`

Comment: Thanks, so if I want to extend the mixin to override `._base_manager` on forms what's the best practice to do this? I assume you are not supposed to subclass a private function like `._base_manager`?

Comment: Which Django version are you using? I couldn't reproduce the issue in Django 2.2 as well as in 3.0

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue in Django 3.0 either. `list(AddPersonForm ().fields['person'].queryset)` is filtered.

Comment: Try `AddPersonForm` without specifying the field qs and just using the standard modelFrom, as amended.

Comment: Now it's just an empty form.

Comment: It seems something probably messes up in your project. I would suggest creating a minimal example again by creating a **fresh Django project** and check whether issue persists. If it still persists, please share the project/reproducible code snippets so that someone can easily help you. @alias51

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in two ways:

**First:** When creating the form instance, add the queryset for the desired field.

```
person_form = AddPersonForm()
person_form.fields["myfield"].queryset = TenantModel.objects.filter(myfield="myvalue")
```

**Second:** Override the field's queryset in the `AddPersonForm` itself.

```
class AddPersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('person', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddPersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
        self.fields['myfield'].queryset = TenantModel.objects.filter(myfield="myvalue")
```

Comment: Please add the reason for downvoting.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure why your code doesn't properly works. Probably you haven't reload django app. You could load queryset in `__init__` of your form class

```py
class AddPersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    person = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=None)

    class Meta:
        model = MyOtherModel
        fields = ('person', )
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['person'].queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't address the bounty guidance.